# SignalR not invoking caller methods - iOS devices

Tags: c#, ios, swift, signalr, asp.net-web-api2

`SignalR` is working fine for all `Android` devices. Server and Clients (Callers) methods are working fine for all android devices but on `iOS` (Swift) server method is invoked but when server invoke caller (`iOS`) method nothing happens, no exception nothing at all.

sample methods is

```
public Task Test()
{
   return Clients.Caller.test("Testing SignalR");
}
```

`Test()` is server method and `test()` is Caller method